# How to have two elements share a box shadow

Tags: html, css, shadow, box-shadow

So I'm in a tricky situation: I have outer `div` wrapper that contains an inner `div` and a `ul` like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <ul id="list">...</ul>
</div>
```

The `#list` has to be absolutely positioned to be right underneath `#box` yet not move it and other elements around the page as it appears and disappears.

Since it's positioned absolutely, if I add a border around `#wrapper`, it only goes around `#box`. `box-shadow` of course acts the same. Problem is, I need a shadow that goes around both elements together seamlessly.

The three solutions I've come across while searching google/stackoverflow are:

1. **Give both elements their own shadow and then use `-webkit-clip-path` to get rid of the top shadow on `#list`, making it look like one shadow going around the group.** While this works, the part where the shadows meet has a weird clippy-looking effect. So this method works, but it doesn't look good. [Link to answer describing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618863/1227353).
2. **Use a spread equal to the negative of the blur and then use 3 shadows, one for each side of `#list`.** Good in theory, but in practice the shadows on the sides now don't go along the full length. [Link to answer describing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853364/1227353). Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a46usqbh/) of me trying it out.
3. **Use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to cover up the overlapping shadow.** This works extremely well for similarly-colored boxes, but my `ul` and `div` have content in them that can't afford to be covered! [Link to answer describing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27675926/1227353)

I'm left in a bit of a jam, as I would really like a shadow around `#box` and `#list` together, but can't seem to find a solution that works for my particular case. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful!

**Note:** I'm actually using the Electron framework, so the solution *must* work on Chrome, but it *only* has to work on Chrome!

Comment: [This is a great answer with example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866131/5601989)

Comment: @JamesBrown problem is, I _need_ `#list` to be absolutely positioned. If it weren't, when it reappears, it would push everything around. I want to appear as a popup over everything else without changing the flow. Unfortunately, this prevents `#wrapper` from actually wrapping it making this non-trivial, but I'm hoping there's some awesome CSS hack some guru out there will bestow that will help :)

Comment: This is a case where an image would actually be really helpful. It sounds very possible - so maybe I'm missing something. It all depends on the items the layout - the shadow color - the things underneath etc.- and how it transitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [css-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

```css
#box {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px black)
}
```

Comment: It says on MDN that `drop-shadow` is basically like `box-shadow` but with hardware acceleration. The syntax seems similar too, how should I use it?

Comment: Worked for me with an element and its :after pseudo element. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why but this worked great! Thank you sir